# setting value null to input control is throwing an exception in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am writing an angular 4 application and need to display nothing in the input control if the value in the drop down list is not selected. I am currently checking if the value if not equal to zero (currentSelectedCoveragePolicy) which means the drop down inst selected but returning null is throwing an exception.

How do i achieve this

Component code

```
get fedExTax(): BackendDto.FedExciseExpense {
    if (this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy != 0) {
      return this.fedExciseExpensesInputs.find(x => x.coveragePolicyTypeId == this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy && x.is953D == this.currentSelected953D);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

html code

```
    <div  class="col-lg-3 col-6 mb-3">
        <label class="col-form-label">{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.INCCAPTIVEEXPENSE.' + FedExciseKey|uppercase|translate}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="fedExTax.value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
            name="{{FedExciseKey}}" numberFormat="numberPercent:.0-2" (ngModelChange)="change()" [required]="true" tooltip="{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.INCCAPTIVEEXPENSE.' + FedExciseKey + 'TOOLTIP'|uppercase|translate}}"
            placement="bottom">
          <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="fedExTax.value"` you have 2 way binding to `fedExTax.value` but only have a getter for `fedExTax`

Comment: Do i also need to add ngValue

Comment: `[ngValue]` is used to tell angular what to put in the model. [(ngModel)] will get **and** set the selected value, but I see you use a custom `(ngModelChange)` . Try using `[ngModel]` instead. You can read more about binding here https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---

Comment: i tried using [ngModel] but still get the following error read property 'value' of null